# Firebase Functions- Get my followers uid and send my post to them?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm developing a social media app.When users share something i handle all stuff on phone with for loop.

Here is my Java code:

```
DatabaseReference reffollowers =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(auth.getUid()).child("followers");
            reffollowers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                        List<String> followerslist = new ArrayList<>();
                        for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            String a = ds.getKey();
                            followerslist.add(a);
                        }

                        DatabaseReference refpost = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts");
                        for(int i=0;i<followerslist.size();i++){
                            refpost.child(followerslist.get(i)).child("unique_post_key").setValue("");
                        }

                        progressDialog.dismiss();


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

But this takes too much time.I want firebase functions to handle it.this is my javascript code but it doesn't work.I don't know javaScript.

This is my javascript code:

```
  const functions = require('firebase-functions');

    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp();

    exports.sharePost = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {

      const postkey = data.text;
      const uid = context.auth.uid;
      var followers_list [];

      var ref = admin.database().ref("users").child(uid).child("followers");
      ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(_child){
          followers_list.push(_child.key);
      });

  });

      for(count2 = 0; count2 < takipci_listesi.lengt; count++) {
        admin.database().ref('posts/' + followers_list[count2]).set({
          postkey: ""
        });

    }
    });
```

Can you guys help me?

Also my firebase databse is like this

```
+root
    +posts
        +user_uid
            +unique_post_key:""
```

When i want to fetch posts i pass post key with this code

```
dataSnapshot.getkey();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this code:

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sharePost = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const postkey = data.text;
  const uid = data.uid;

  var list= [];

  var db = admin.database();

var ref = db.ref("users").child(uid).child("followers");
  ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    list.push(childKey);
    console.log(list[list.length-1]+" eklendi");
    console.log("list size : "+list.length);
  });
  var refsave = db.ref("posts");

  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    refsave.child(list[i]).set({
       postkey:"a"
    });
    console.log(list[i]+" yazıldı");
  }

});

});
```